# How to authenticate docker login in Ubuntu 20.0 LTE

Tags: docker, artifactory, ubuntu-20.04

I tried login to JFrog artifactory using docker commands:

```
root@dxc:/home/dxc# echo ${API_Key} | docker login --username 320060162 --password-stdin
```

But I am facing with the below error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I tried to check config.json file:

```
root@dxc:/home/dxc# cd .docker/
root@dxc:/home/dxc/.docker# cat config.json
{
    "auths": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give artifactory endpoint as well in the docker login command.

> echo "your_password" | docker **login your_domain.jfrog.io** --username "username" --password-stdin

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set your credentials in the config.json file as below:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "<the Docker repository endpoint in Artifactory>": {
            "auth": "<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> (converted to base 64)",
            "email": "youremail@email.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using username as ID and Password as API key from Artifactory, getting error for that.

Comment: Error :  **Error response from daemon: unauthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest**
root@dxc:/home#                                                                                                                          config.json: {
    "auths": {
        "https://artifactory.com:443/artifactory": {
            "auth": "MzIwMTY1MDgyOkFQNkRaSGtqcWJTb1c2NmVNS3pEOVBOTVJHZg==",
            "email": "santoshkumar.angadi@yahoo.com"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I have complete access but still I am getting like above error.

Comment: Now I am trying to run docker pull hello-world but I am getting below error, please help me to resolve this.                                                                                                                         `dxc@dxc:~$ sudo docker pull hello-world
[sudo] password for dxc:
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
dxc@dxc:~$`

Comment: Anything needs to be changes in proxy.conf for docker? i am trying this in Ubuntu 20